# Error in rowMeans(results, na.rm = T) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Tags: arrays, r, analytics

I am trying to follow an example of some R code from [this site](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~lgarmire/RNASeqPowerCalculator.htm), but am getting the error as seen below.

```
>Results = RS_simulation(sims=5, params=params, budget=3000, designtype = "one factor", nmax = 20, nmin = 5, program="DESeq")
    [1] "DESeq"
> plot(rownames(results),rowMeans(results, na.rm=T), main="DESeq simulations on Bottomly Dataset", xlab = "number of replicates", ylab = "Power")
    Error in rowMeans(results, na.rm = T) : 
      'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

I have tried this command as well, but get this:

```
> plot(rownames(results),rowMeans(results[, na.rm=T, drop=FALSE]), main="DESeq simulations on Bottomly Dataset", xlab = "number of replicates", ylab = "Power", drop=FALSE)
Error in results[, na.rm = T, drop = FALSE] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Any help with this? Always trying to get better at R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original assignment statement, you save the output from the `RS_simulation()` call to a variable called `Results` and then you try plotting stuff from `results`.  R is case-sensitive - consistent case and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, saved a lot of headache